How to add damped constraint force to constrained dynamics simulation?
I have implemented a constraint dynamics physics simulation as proposed by Andrew Witkin et al 1990, but I cannot get the initial constraint "snapping" correctly.
I implemented
$$ JWJ^{T} \lambda = −\dot{J} \dot{q} − J W Q − k_s C − k_d \dot{C}$$
(from here, where $J$ is the jacobian of $C$ with respect with particle positions, $W$ is the weight of each particle, $q$ is the velocity of the particles, $Q$ is the particles accelerations, $C$ is the constraint function value for each constraint, and $\dot{C}$ is the derivative of $C$ with respect to particle positions, $k_s$ and $k_d$ are constants to prevent drift) as:
# f = dJ @ dq + J @ W @ Q + ks * C + kd * dC
# g = J @ W @ J.T
f, g, J, c = SimulationFunctions.matrices(self.ks, self.kd, self.particles, self.constraints)

# Solve for λ in g λ = -f, minimizing ||g λ + f||, where f = dJ dq + J W Q + ks C + kd dC and g = J W J.T

r: scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult = scipy.optimize.least_squares(lambda l: g @ l + f, np.zeros_like(f),
                                                                jac=lambda _: g, method='trf')
l: np.ndarray = r.x
self.error = f"constraint {c} solve {np.linalg.norm(g * l + f)}"

I want to replace the $k_s C + k_d \dot{C}$ term with a better cost that allows the system to smoothly transition into satisfying the constraint, like a "critically damped system". I also get cases where the system simply cannot reach the constraint and explodes or cases where the constraint is satisfied but acts as a spring, causing the system to accelerate.
Here is an example with timestep 0.00001, $k_s = 0.0001$, $k_d = 0.01$ where the particle should approach, then become stationary on a small constraint:

Here is another example with timestep 0.00001, $k_s = 0.0001$, $k_d = 0.01$ where the particle overshoots and then goes back to the constraint, also I think the acceleration curve is wrong, having low acceleration initially and then accelerating and overshooting:

Here is an example with timestep 0.00001, $k_s = 0.001$, $k_d = 0.1$ where a distance constraint causes problems by adding velocity to the system (sorry the quality is bad, I had trouble uploading bigger gifs):

How should I go about getting a "critically damped system" behaviour when the constraint is not satisfied?
My code is here https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/Interactive-Dynamics-Physics-Simulations/tree/master.
Note: I have tried to use the harmonic oscillator model as proposed here but this doesn't work, as the constraint function doesn't have properties that force the system to always behave as a harmonic oscillator. To do this I changed the cost term to: $JWJ^{T} \lambda = −\dot{J} \dot{q} − J W Q − k_s C − \sqrt{4 m k_s} \dot{C} $ (I set $m = 1$ and also set all masses for all particles to 1 to simplify for the test).
Here is the first test with timestep 0.00001, $k_s = 0.001$, $k_d = \sqrt{4*k_s} = 0.0632$:

Second test (timestep 0.00001, $k_s = 0.001$, $k_d = \sqrt{4*k_s} = 0.0632$):

But for the third test it fails catastrophically (timestep 0.00001, $k_s = 0.001$, $k_d = \sqrt{4*k_s} = 0.0632$):

So this didn't work, I think it is because the acceleration of the system (with or without damping) is not taken into account when calculating the damping force. In other words, this is just setting $\ddot{C} = − k_s C − \sqrt{4 m k_s} \dot{C}$ which doesn't really make sense.

Can you type your problem using MathJax so we can understand what your objective function and what your constraints are?

@nicoguaro I have typed the central equation in MathJax, I can give constraint examples, but the program is meant to be modular as to be able to implement any constraint function. I don't know how much info I should give on the simulation dynamics.

The MIT OCW notes that you reference show the conventional model
of a spring-mass system with viscous damping that is found in
many calculus and physics texts. If you say that it "doesn't work"
you need to explain in some detail why the damping model you want
is not represented by this equation.

@BillGreene "The MIT OCW notes that you reference show the conventional model of a spring-mass system with viscous damping that is found in many calculus and physics texts." I don't think that's correct, as critically damped system evaluate the position velocity and acceleration to generate the $k,b$ values, but the constraint term doesn't actually take velocity or acceleration into account. I have tried setting $k_d = 4 * W * k_s$ but it doesn't always work. I can add visual examples to the question if you want.

@BillGreene I tried to add more info to the question, sorry if its difficult to understand, thanks for your time.

In your equation $JWJ^{T} \lambda = −\dot{J} \dot{q} − J W Q − k_s C − k_d \dot{C}$, what is $J$, $W$, $q$, $Q$, $k_s$, $C$, and $k_d$?

@nicoguaro I added what each value is.

Every occurrence of "it doesn't work" should have more of an explanation to it. What is it that you expected? What exactly happens? How specifically are they different?

@WolfgangBangerth added a few test cases I used, and gifs that let you see the problems, but I had trouble compressing the gifs to upload so they are at a very low framerate, but you can see the time of the simulation on top (sum of timesteps until that moment)

I'm trying to understand your question (please forgive me in case my comment is inappropriate): are you trying to set up a constrained dynamics symulation, where the system starts out not satisfying the contraints and then reaches the condition where it satisfies that, by means of some kind of dumping? If so, it seems that you are misuing the numerical method, as the damping term is meant to compensate for numerical errors that accumulate, not for playing a physical role. Also, I bet the unsatisfied constraint causes lots of troubles in the simulation (it's meant to be satisfied from begining)

@Rigel "where the system starts out not satisfying the contraints and then reaches the condition where it satisfies that, by means of some kind of dumping?"Yes.
"as the damping term is meant to compensate for numerical errors that accumulate, not for playing a physical role." I understand that the paper's damping is meant to compensate the numercal part (I'm not that sure it does in general), that's why I'm asking for some other kind of damping for my case. "I bet the unsatisfied constraint causes lots of troubles in the simulation" it does, that's why I'm trying to fix the troubles it causes

The most basic idea that I would suggest, is to simply simulate a (critically?) damped oscillator until the particles are sufficiently close to meet the contraints (no constrained dynamics up to this point). Then, enforce the constraints by using the method you described above. Of course, this is all but trivial to implement, and the details highly depend on the specific system that you are trying to simulate (which I don't know enough about)

@Rigel "details highly depend on the specific system that you are trying to simulate" I don't want to simulate any specific system, I want to create a general simulator. I had thought of your solution, but "move towards constraint without constraint dynamics" is basically impossible, that's why implemented this thing in the first place. The thing is that using the current system I can obtain an orthogonal vector towards the constraints ($J^T \lambda$), but how to modify the cost term to actually follow $J^T \lambda$ is my question. I would also prefer the system to not over accelerate.

@Rigel There might be some way to perform gradient descent on C. There also is the issue of determining when the system is "far enough" from the constraint, as deciding when one constraint following mechanism should be used and not the other doesn't seem trivial for arbitrary constraint functions.

Actually, I think the main reason why your method does not work in general (but only in special cases) is that using forces that are orthogonal to the constraints hypersurfaces does not guarantee that you can reach the point where $C=0$. That is only guaranteed when the particles are just slightly off from the positions that make $C=0$ (and of course I believe the $C_i$s have to be differentiable).

I don't expect gradient descent on $C$, or rather on $C^T C$, to work in general, either. Gradient descent finds a local minimum, not the global one (and you want the global one, i.e. the particle positions such that $C^T C =0$).

Are you sure you cannot restrict the set of $C_i$s that you are interested in?

@Rigel "Are you sure you cannot restrict the set of $C_is$ that you are interested in?" I wouldn't know what restrictions to apply. Or what they'd imply.

It seems there is no easy answer to your question, and I think what you are trying to do is not possible unless you restrict somehow the set of constraints that you want to consider.
As a simple example to demostrante that it is not possible to (or at least there is no known way to) solve the problem in general, we can consider the 1-D case.
Let's imagine that you were able to define and implement an algorithm that can simulate a particle that moves along a line until it quitely falls onto a point that is a zero of a generic function $C$. Then you can just use that algorithm to find zeros of any kind of function of a real parameter. This would be worth much more than a Fields medal.
Moreover, I would like to share some intuitions about this problem, even though I could not sketch out formal statements, nor formal proofs.
Sticking to the 1-D case, if you restrict your algorithm to constraint functions $C$ that are monotonic, twice differentiable, amd apply to one particle each, the game could be feasible (gradient descent on $C^2$ could definitely be an option, or maybe the scheme that you were trying to use could work already).
If it works, you could try to scale up to more dimensions, but you have to apply other notions rather than the monotonic one, which would not make sense when you have greater dimensionality (maybe the function should have no local minima/maxima except for those that are also zeros?).

"Let's imagine that you were able to define and implement an algorithm that can simulate a particle that moves along a line until it quitely falls onto a point that is a zero of a generic function C." My intuition says that this is similar to the gradient descent problem for perceptron neural networks, and that a function C can be defined in terms of nonlinearly activated perceptrons without loss of (input-output) generality.

$C$ needs to be twice differentiable in terms of $(x,y)$ position for $J$ and $\dot{J}$ to make sense see readme at https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/Interactive-Dynamics-Physics-Simulations

@EmmanuelMess thanks for spotting the mistake, I fixed the answer to mention that C has to be twice differentiable.

I cannot comment on perceptron neural networks, as I don't know enough of that topic. But it will be interesting to see if you find some interesting partial solution to your problem following that path.

"if you restrict your algorithm to constraint functions C that are monotonic and twice differentiable, the game could be feasible" Thinking about this a bit more, I think that even when all constraints are monotonic, if constraints are function of other points, you can create systems that endlessly move around a zero, even when they should not. The property on constraint functions should involve some kind of term on how it interacts with other constraint functions. Proving such property sounds like proving that the system will have some kind of Lyapunov stability maybe?

Indeed, I was only considering the simplest case, where constraints apply each to one particle only. Can you provide an example where constraints that apply to more particles lead to particles that would instead endlessly move around zero? I agree they might exist, but having an example already would increase the chances that I can find some time to help you with the analysis

I edite the answer to mention that I refer to single particle constraints

"Can you provide an example where constraints that apply to more particles lead to particles that would instead endlessly move around zero?" The specific case depends on the term $ - k_s C - k_d \dot{C}$ (or its replacement). In general something like two big structures attached by a single distance constraint will lead to numerical error large enough to eternally "spring back and forth" never actually converging. Other cases involve crafting constraints so that the function is not easy to minimize.

I have become convinced that the solution lies in creating a globally asymptotically stable (GAS) system, where the cost term $k_s C + k_d \dot{C}$ is replaced by a cost function that generates the GAS system. If the cost function cannot be found, then the system would not collapse into the constraints, and is broken. If the cost is found, then it eventually does collapse, in a way similar to the critically damped system, which is what I asked in the question.
